# current Day + N days is the day of next month or previous month

Tags: android

ANDROID:

Wanted to know whether is there any API or workaround to know that DAY X + N DAYS ahead or behind was the day that will be / was of next month / previous month.

Comment: That's not directly available AFAIK.You need to prepare one for yourself.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static Date getCurrentDatePlusDays(int days) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(new Date());
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, days);
        Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
        return newDate;
    }
```

then check the month or year.